# Getting the Machine Type and other Hardware details through Cocoa API

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, profiler

On iOS, there is a [UIDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) class which lets you get tons of great info about the device model, operating system etc…

I am looking for something equivalent on the Mac. I know about calling `system_profiler` from the command line, but even the `mini` setting takes several seconds to get any info.

I am interested in fast ways to get the machine type (Macbook Air, Mac Mini, etc…), OS version, and other quick machine details from within a Mac App. The details are going o be used as a footer on support emails sent from within the app. Is there any equivalent to UIDevice, or another **fast** way to get some info that could help describe a user's machine?

Answer (score 22):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

+ (NSString *)machineModel
{
    size_t len = 0;
    sysctlbyname("hw.model", NULL, &len, NULL, 0);

    if (len)
    {
        char *model = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
        sysctlbyname("hw.model", model, &len, NULL, 0);
        NSString *model_ns = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:model];
        free(model);
        return model_ns;
    }

    return @"Just an Apple Computer"; //in case model name can't be read
}
```

---

Swift version (just swap `hw.model` for `hw.machine`) is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25467259/308315

Comment: can we also get some other information like Processor name "Intel i5" Ram type etc. @erkanyildiz

Answer (score 1):

Does calling `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType` give you what you need? It returns very quickly and returns some basic hardware info.  You can find out what other data you can request by calling `system_profiler -listDataTypes`.  I think the other piece to your puzzle will be `system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in device class, as in iOS.

You'll need to use the [Gestalt Manager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Gestalt_Manager/Reference/reference.html) to investigate the operating environment.

Comment: Gestalt is deprecated in OS X v10.8 (Mountain Lion). And it seems there is no way to do this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Mac has **ProcessInfo** class for all the Mac Machine related info

Few Use case -

1. ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersion
2. ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment (many options)

check this link
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo