# Using sysctlbyname() from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I’m using the code from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Jaybles/1323251) to determine which iOS device (e.g. `iPhone5,1`) my app is running on:

```
- (NSString *)platform
{
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine];
    free(machine);
    return platform;
}
```

[The Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_12) indicates that C data types are well-supported, but it doesn’t say anything about C functions. Is there a pure Swift way to retrieve the machine identifier, or will I have to bridge into Objective-C for this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can do the same in Swift (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
func platform() -> String {
    var size : Int = 0 // as Ben Stahl noticed in his answer
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", nil, &size, nil, 0)
    var machine = [CChar](count: size, repeatedValue: 0)
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", &machine, &size, nil, 0)
    return String.fromCString(machine)!
}
```

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
func platform() -> String {
    var size = 0
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", nil, &size, nil, 0)
    var machine = [CChar](repeating: 0,  count: size)
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", &machine, &size, nil, 0)
    return String(cString: machine)
}
```

Comment: Well I’ll be darned. I guess I should have tried this first. Thanks!

Comment: What are the error checks you omitted, that should be added in this function? Thanks.

Comment: @EmilAdz: [`sysctlbyname()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysctlbyname.3.html) has a *return value* which is zero on success and -1 on failure.

Comment: So what should I check test in case the method returned -1 in case of failure?

Comment: @EmilAdz: I am not sure what you are asking for. If a system call fails then the global variable `errno` is set to an integer indicating the failure reason. It is up to you what to do in that case (return a default value, return nil, abort the program, ...) – In this particular case I do not think that `sysctlbyname()` will ever fail if you pass valid parameters. I just mentioned that for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @MartinR, oh... so actually for this specific method there are no other additional checks I need to added for error checking. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @EmilAdz: Also `String.fromCString(machine)` could fail (i.e. return nil) if the machine name is not a valid UTF-8 string.

Comment: @MartinR, Thanks for the heads up. Do I have any way to test if a valid UTF-8 string is provided?

Comment: This no longer works in Swift 2.1. Error: '&' used with non-inout argument of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>

Comment: @MartinR I got it to work, maybe you can review for correctness: https://gist.github.com/nanaimostudio/00d62540fec410bad153

Comment: @Boon: The only necessary change is `UInt` -> `Int` in the first line, as already mentioned in a comment after that line (and also noticed in the other answer). – I have updated the answer now so that it directly compiles in all current Swift versions.

Answer (score 16):

As of Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 beta-2), @MartinR's code above needs to be modified slightly. sysctlbyname needs a CChar array (i.e. C string) for the first parameter, and an Int (instead of Uint) for the "size" parameter.

```
func platformModelString() -> String? {
    if let key = "hw.machine".cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        var size: Int = 0
        sysctlbyname(key, nil, &size, nil, 0)
        var machine = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(size))
        sysctlbyname(key, &machine, &size, nil, 0)
        return String(cString: machine)
    }
    return nil
}
```

EDIT: Updated 2017-01-04 for **Swift 3** syntax

Comment: You are right about the type of the size parameter. But passing a Swift string to an `UnsafePointer<Int8>` parameter still works in Swift 1.2, the compiler will convert that automatically.

Comment: I think you’ve got an extra `}` at the end of the function, right?

Comment: @bdesham Yeah, sorry about extra } ... sloppy copy-paste job. Fixed.