# sysctlbyname failing in swift 1.2

Tags: swift

I had this code working in swift 1.1
Not sure how to fix it

```
var deviceModelIdentifier: String {
    var size : UInt = 0 // Swift 1.2: var size : Int = 0 (as Ben Stahl noticed in his answer)
    //sysctlbyname(_: UnsafePointer<Int8>, _: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, _: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>, _: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, _: Int)
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", nil, &size, nil, 0)
    var machine = [CChar](count: Int(size), repeatedValue: 0)
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", &machine, &size, nil, 0)
    return String.fromCString(machine)!
}
```

error: cannot invoke 'sysctlbyname' with an argument list of type '(String, nil, inout UInt, nil, Int)'
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", nil, &size, nil, 0)
        ^
error: cannot invoke 'sysctlbyname' with an argument list of type '(String, inout [(CChar)], inout UInt, nil, Int)'
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", &machine, &size, nil, 0)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: *"Not sure how to fix it"* – Did you read the comment in the second line ?

Comment: Btw., this is where the code seems to come from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467082/using-sysctlbyname-from-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is there in the comment in your code: Size is now `Int` rather than `Uint` in 1.2, so this compiles:

```
var deviceModelIdentifier: String {
    var size : Int = 0
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", nil, &size, nil, 0)
    var machine = [CChar](count: size, repeatedValue: 0)
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", &machine, &size, nil, 0)
    return String.fromCString(machine)!
}
```

(you can also write `var size : size_t = 0` if you prefer)

Error message hints at this when you wade through the unsafe pointer boiler plate:

> note: expected an argument list of type '(UnsafePointer< Int8 >,
>   UnsafeMutablePointer< Void >, UnsafeMutablePointer<**Int**>,
>   UnsafeMutablePointer< Void >, Int)'

Comment: Thanks @Airspeed :) i totally missed that

Answer (score 0):

The Swift 4.0 version

```
var deviceModel: String {
    var size : Int = 0
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", nil, &size, nil, 0)
    var machine = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: size)
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", &machine, &size, nil, 0)
    return String(cString: machine, encoding: .utf8)!
}
```