# How to pass two Strings from Swift to a C++ function, and getting an array of Integers?

Tags: c++, macos, swift

I am trying to pass two `Strings` from Swift to the C++ function, handle them there, and then return an array of integers (probally a vector), not sure yet.

I've tried it with (C++ function declaration):

```
void exmaple(char* one, char* two);
```

But was not able to pass the strings from Swift to C++.

**Then I changed the function a little:**

```
void example(void* one, void* two)
{
    string &a = *reinterpret_cast<string*>(one);
    string &b = *reinterpret_cast<string*>(two);

    cout<<"String b is: "<<b<<endl;
}
```

**and tried calling the function in Swift:**

```
let aStr = UnsafeMutablePointer<String>.alloc(10)
aStr.initialize("stringA")

let bStr = UnsafeMutablePointer<String>.alloc(10)
bStr.initialize("stringB")

example(aStr, bStr)
```

But the only output I get is:

```
String b is:
```

How can I pass two Strings from Swift to a C++ function, and then return an array/vector of integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift has some magic bridging that allows you to pass regular Swift strings directly into C functions.  For example, `strlen` has the signature `size_t  strlen(const char *)`, which comes into Swift as `func strlen(_: UnsafePointer<Int8>) -> UInt` but you can call it with ordinary strings like this:

```
import Darwin

let greeting: String = "Hello!"

strlen(greeting)   // returns 6

strlen("Goodbye")  // returns 7
```

And the compiler will automatically generate null-terminated C strings for the call.

The last part of your question is much trickier unfortunately.  Not only is there actually no bridging to C++, only C and Objective-C, there most definitely won't be the ability to pass back a C++ vector.  Your best bet is either to go via an Objective-C layer and pass back an `NSArray`, or to use C-style pass in an empty buffer and have the function write the values into it.

Comment: Okay, but how do I pass the Strings to the C++ function? I declared the function with const char* parameter, but cant get it working on the Swift side:         let bStr = UnsafeMutablePointer<String>.alloc(1)
        bStr.initialize("example")
        
        exampleFunc(bStr) -> "Cannot invoke example with arguments..."

Comment: No need for unsafe mutable anything.  Just pass in the String.  Look at my example, `strlen` takes a `const char *` but I am passing in a `String` as an argument.

Comment: Just passing the String or NSString didnt work, I got it working with converting the NSString to a cString, and passing it! Now I just need to return an array of Integers or vector of Integers.. The hard part, as you said..

Comment: You shouldn't need to convert it to an NSString.  Just pass the String straight in.  For an example of how a C function can receive an array from Swift and populate it, take a look at how `sysctlbyname` (which takes a buffer and populates it) is being called in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25467259/3925941

Comment: You are right. Works the same with just the String. Any Idea for the return though? I get problems in the extern "C" with the vector type.. Or how could I pass back a NSArray?

Comment: Look at that link in my prev comment.  You can create an array and pass that in to be received in C as a pointer to a buffer (with a length argument) to be populated.