# How to know latest ios version available programatically in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios12

Is there any way we can find out the latest ios version available on device programmatically. Like latest ios version now is 12.2

Comment: You can not get the latest ios version available, But you can get the current version of ios using the following code. "var systemVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion"

Comment: Yeah i know, but I want the latest ios version

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple API list you can check latest iOS version with below command. You have to run this command in terminal.

`curl -L http://phobos.apple.com./version`

You will get all information about the all versions.

Comment: This does not answer the question of "how to know programmatically in Swift".

Comment: What is the key path of the latest version within this gargantuan XML file?

Comment: @ThomasHaz Did you get the key path for latest version?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to find the latest iOS version released. It is totally impractical approach because how can `UIDevice` or `Any` class know which is the latest iOS was released without updating device operating system.

**Now go with other possibilities**

There are any apple APIs which provide latest release information?

Unfortunately, There are no such APIs which provide information like this.

**Alternatives**

You can create custom APIs which is providing the latest release information. Once latest iOS will release then update in server back-end. Then you can check which is the latest iOS version.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't found the solution but I got it from this link: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50910926/how-can-i-determine-the-latest-ios-version-programmatically-using-swift)

Just call the API

```
curl -L http://phobos.apple.com./version
```

and search for the key such as "iPhone10, 1" or whatever device you are looking for. You will find the version under key "Product Version"

```
<key>ProductVersion</key>
<string>12.3.1</string>
```